# Elasctic Search is working at port 9200 but Kibana is not working

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Hello I am starting work with kibana and elasticsearch. I am being able to run elasticsearch at port 9200 but kibana is not running at port 5601. The following two images are given for clarification
[image]

[image]

Kibana is not running and showing the page is not available

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kibana doesn't support space in the folder name. Your folder name is

```
GA Works
```

Remove the space between those two words kibana will then run without errors and you will be able to access at

```
http://localhost:5601
```

You can rename the folder with

```
GA_Works
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you

**a)** Set the elasticsearch_url to point at your Elasticsearch instance in file kibana/config.yml?

**b)** Run ./bin/kibana (or bin\kibana.bat on windows) (after setting the above config)

?

Comment: I have done so. Probably you mean adding this line: elasticsearch_url: "http://localhost:9200" . Am I right?

Comment: Yeah. You could try with *http://* before the name, or other variations (maybe without the port number) to see if it works.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe look at the kibana logs to see if it is really running. Maybe it's hit an error.

Comment: I am getting the following error:C:\Users\tb\Desktop\GA Works\kibana-4.0.0\kibana-4.0.0\bin>kibana.bat
'C:\Users\tb\Desktop\GA' is not recognized as an internal or external comman
d,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\tb\Desktop\GA Works\kibana-4.0.0\kibana-4.0.0\bin>

Comment: I think you're typing the wrong command on the command line. Use `cd` to navigate to the `bin` folder and then just type `kibana.bat` and then hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all of the above and still it doesn't work make sure that the kibana process is running first. I found that /etc/init.d/kibana4_init doesn't start the process. If that is the case then try: opt/kibana/bin/kibana.
I also made kibana user:group owner of the folder/files.

Comment: The OP's question has already been answered, and your answer does not even refer to any information the OP gave.